# How to clone function in Qt script?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtscript

I want to send Qt script data into another thread. To do that, I must copy the data, since the `QScriptValue` objects refer to javascript objects, rather than containing them.

How can I clone a function? This isn't very good, cloning `entry` into `subEntry`:

```
subEntry = target.engine()->evaluate("("+entry.toString()+")");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this isn't very good"? What do you wish to improve? To make it any better, you'd need to implement function cloning in the `QtScript` module's code itself. I.e. you need to patch Qt.

Comment: @KubaOber well, the above fails for native functions for example. It also doesn't clone the function's captured scope, but I guess I *could* live without that. But if there's any binding to an object (`Function.prototype.bind`) that won't work either.

Comment: This requires a Qt patch. Any chance you could do use the modern `QJSEngine`? It'd be easier to implement there AFAICT.